# PHP captura texto de data

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma lista com esses valores:

```
<li data-breadcrumb="Caixa 1 - Quarto 2 - Casa 3"> Conteúdo </li>
```

E gostaria de inverter a ordem deles em PHP.

Eu fiz uma função

```
function inverte_breadcrumb($texto){
 $texto = explode(' - ', $texto);
 $texto = array_reverse($texto);
 $texto = implode(' - ', $texto);

 return $texto;
}
```

e com o preg_replace pensei em fazer o seguinte:

```
$novaslinhas = preg_replace("/data-breadcrumb="(.*)"/", 'data-breadcrumb="' . inverte_breadcrumb("$1") . '"', $novaslinhas);
```

Mas, ele não chama a função.

Alguém sabe o porquê?

Comment: primeiro, você está fazendo uma bagunça delimitando a string com aspas duplas e ao mesmo tempo usando aspas duplas sem escape. Segundo, você tenta aplicar uma função com o valor "$1", ela até será chamada sim, mas é sem efeito (não vai inverter nada, pois "$1" não tem traços. Ponha um `print_r($texto)` dentro da função inverte_breadcrumb que você vai ver que ela será chamada (depois de você consertar as aspas). Espero que nessas alturas do comentário você já tenha percebido que a função "inverte" será chamada antes do replace, ou seja, não vai surtir o efeito que você pretende.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sera possível utilizando a função [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php) pois a mesma recebe valor do tipo string ou array com strings no parâmetro `replacement`

Para obter o resultado, utilize a função [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php) executar um callback.

uso:

```
preg_replace_callback('expressão', 'callback', 'string');
```

seu código:

```
$novaslinhas = preg_replace_callback("/data-breadcrumb=\"(.*)\"/",
                                               'inverte_breadcrumb', $novaslinhas);
```

note que o nome da função foi informado como uma string, agora mude a primeira linha da função, informando o índice que no caso é 1:

```
$texto = explode(' - ', $texto[1]);
```

altere também o retorno, pois deve ser retornado uma string que será substituta:

```
return 'data-breadcrumb="'. $texto . '"';
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/VariableElasticBytecode)

#### Código completo:

```
function inverte_breadcrumb($texto){
  $texto = explode(' - ', $texto[1]);
  $texto = array_reverse($texto);
  $texto = implode(' - ', $texto);
  return 'data-breadcrumb="'. $texto . '"';
}

$novaslinhas = preg_replace_callback("/data-breadcrumb=\"(.*)\"/", 'inverte_breadcrumb', $novaslinhas);
```

#### Referências:

- [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)
- [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: Perfeito cara, eu sei que tenho muito o que aprender ainda, mas, valeu pela ajuda!!!